# dateformat is divided and i get totally different value

Tags: javascript, date-format

i have a little javascript that should bring some values to change the link, but the problem is that date format is written like: dd/mm/year thus the day is divided by month then by year :) here is the function:

```
function show_sales(employee_id,start_date,finish_date)
    {
      var url_str = "#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_showsales_emp"
      url_str = url_str + '&employee_id=' + employee_id;
      url_str = url_str + '&start_date=' + start_date;
      url_str = url_str + '&finish_date=' + finish_date;
      AjaxPageLoad(url_str,'salesdiv_' + employee_id,1,'Yükleniyor');
    }
```

as u can see i want to get the start date and finish date to change the link, but instead it counts the value )) so instead of getting: 02/01/2012 i get: 0.0009940357852882703 :) thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope there is a prob in function call

```
function show_sales(1,'12/3/2008','15/5/2012');
```

make sure that date is formatted as string

Comment: it says missing formal parameter :(

Comment: these string notations are should be used in the place where function is called :)

Comment: i am sure pls recheck the parameters it should be with in codes ... it will work

Comment: what if the dates are displayed like

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I have understand you but this may help:

```
function show_sales(employee_id,start_date,finish_date)
{
    var url_str = "#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_showsales_emp"
    url_str = url_str + '&employee_id=' + encodeURIComponent(employee_id);
    url_str = url_str + '&start_date=' + encodeURIComponent(start_date);
    url_str = url_str + '&finish_date=' + encodeURIComponent(finish_date);
    AjaxPageLoad(url_str,'salesdiv_' + employee_id,1,'Yükleniyor');
}
```

Comment: no, i get the same values :( plus u have a mistake `'&finish_date=' + enodeURIComponent(finish_date);` `encode`